# Images not showing up when posting in wordpress using simple grid

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, elementor

How I can fix it . When using image with upload that time, it's working but when use file is already uploaded it not show. Now I'm using elementor free version and  using simple grid
Thank you.

I need to fix this problem without using elementor proversion.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJBTk.png)